# Is there a logic to the file name Word 2013 suggests on first save from the documents text?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

The first time I save a document in Word 2013 it grabs some words from the beginning of the document to suggest as a file name. Sometimes it's one word, sometimes several. I can't see a pattern to what it suggests, other than it starts from the first word. Is there a way without cut and past to tell it what to use?

Answer (score 1):

When you save a Word document for the first time, Word typically uses the first paragraph of the document as the suggested file name in the Save As dialog box. In reality, this choice for a default file name is the second choice for Word. It will use your document title as the default file name, provided you have set one.

If you’ve set the “Title” property for the document, Word uses that as the suggested file name when you first save the document. If you want the same default file name to be used for all documents of a specific type, you can create a template for use with those documents and set the “Title” property in the template.

To set a document title in a template, follow these general steps:

1. Open the template file (it has a .dotx extension).
2. Click **File > Info > Properties > Advanced Properties**. This displays the Properties dialog box for the template.
3. Make sure the **Summary** tab is selected (it should be selected by default).
4. Change the contents of the **Title** field to the default file name you want to use. You do not need to include the .docx portion of the file name.
5. Click on **OK** to close the dialog box.
6. Save and close the template.

[image]

Reference:
[View or change the properties for an Office file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-or-change-the-properties-for-an-office-file-21d604c2-481e-4379-8e54-1dd4622c6b75)

[Changing the Default File Name](https://word.tips.net/T000964_Changing_the_Default_File_Name.html)

[How to Change the Default File Name Used When Saving Word Documents](https://www.howtogeek.com/220794/how-to-change-the-default-file-name-used-when-saving-word-documents/)

Answer (score 0):

I assume the headline of your documents rarely contains what you want as file name. To avoid that Word gives any suggestion, you may create your file in Windows Explorer *before* beginning to type your text:
 1. right click in empty area
 2. choose "New / Word document"
 3. enter the desired file name
 4. press Enter twice to start Word